# iOS WKWebView allow to attach input-file from local storage

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am developing iOS mobile app with webview which allow user to attach image or capture image from Local storage.

[image]

Is there anyways to upload/capture image from local storage instead of App Gallery?

Thank you in advance for support.

Comment: Your question is unclear. How did you manage to upload image from app gallry instead of local storage on the first place? Or do you mean Image gallery? And if so, what exactly didn't work for you?

Comment: Thank Kiril, the idea is to access local storage instead of gallery.